# java apache http package -- how can I force GET to ignore cache?

Tags: java, android, http

I'm using `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet` to read a plain text file from the server.  The server isn't sending any kind of "expires" header.  I find that repeated calls to HttpGet are returning an out-of-date version of the text file, obviously from some sort of cache.

Is there a way to force the GET to go to the server instead of the cache?

Comment: What headers are you sending to the server? Have you tried from a browser, such as Chrome? What headers does the server responds with (particularly on secondary responses) related to caching, expiration and last modified?

Comment: It works fine from Chrome; if I change the text file, Chrome picks it up no problem when I do a refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Comment: Note: the best solution is to set the Last Modified header from the server and then check, from the server, for the 'If-Modified-Since' header from the client, and respond with 304 from the server if it is not newer (allowing the requesting browser to use its cache, while minimizing bandwidth for both the client and server, with the potential for the most up-to-date result). This of course assumes that you know when the file was last modified, but I suspect you can use the file system to check that date/time for you.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll try that approach as well.

Comment: Just a follow-up: I'm using both the Cache-Control and If-Modified-Since headers and am entirely satisfied with the results.  Thanks everybody.